# How much current does a DM3 connector require?

Tags: pic, sd

I'm trying to have my PIC32MX470F512L communicate with the sd card for some time now without success (using harmony sd card example)

I checked that the pins CMD,CLK,DAT0,DAT3 are receiving a signal.

So now im questioning what is the minimum and maximum of current the micro sd card with SPI when in a DM3 micro SD connector? because i've been testing with ICD3 power, that provides only 100mA for both pic, sd card and other small things.

the model i'm using for sd card connector is DM3CS-SF

[image]

Comment: The connector is just a set of contacts in a housing. It doesn't *require* any particular current.

Answer (score 2):

For the connector there is no minimum current requirement as brhanns mentioned it's just a set of contacts and a housing. Now for the SD card you insert into it you need to make sure it is making a good connection to GND and VDD so that it can send and receive data.

Comment: There is signal on the pins of the connector, then i put the sd card i closed it, the strange thing is that it receives a signal with SPO but doesn't give any signal back to SPI.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is the power requirement for the SD card. This is available from the card datasheet. Plan for about 400mA max. Typical cards are about 300mA max. So 100mA (or less if it's shared) isn't really enough.